# Check if all radio buttons are checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i want to check some radio buttons to allow the user to click a link (otherway it should appeal a allert).

here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.aerosoft.de" id="a_next">aerosoft.de</a>

            <li class="radiobutton"><span class="name">Struct. Temp. Indic.> 38°C -not exceed 55°C</span>
            <input name="1" type="radio" value="other" /></li>
            <li class="radiobutton"><span class="name">Airplane Documents - check </span>
            <input name="2" type="radio" value="other" /></li>
            <li class="radiobutton"><span class="name">Flight Control Lock - removed</span>
            <input name="3" type="radio" value="other" /></li>
</body>
</html>
```

The user have to check all 3 Radiobuttons to let the link work, otherway if he just have check 2 radiobuttons he should get a alert if he click on the link.

Would be great if someone could help :/

Greets
Fabian

Comment: Why are you using radio buttons instead of checkboxes? Radio buttons are intended for use in groups where only one can be selected at a time (and clicking one deselects the previously selected one).

Comment: needed to be done :/ with checkboxes i also done it ... but i need to use radio buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the click event on the link. Loop through the radios, and if any are not checked display the alert and return false to cancel the click's default action (i.e., cancel the navigation).

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("a_next").onclick = function(e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var els = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
            i;
        for (i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
            if (!els[i].checked) {
                alert("Your message here.");
                e.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t9wqc/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, its much cleaner..

**See full [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/tqFbQ/)**

```
<a href="#">aerosoft.de</a>


var link = "http://www.aerosoft.de" ;

$('input').change(function(){
   var allChecked = $('input:checked').length == 3;

    if(allChecked ){
      $('#a_next').attr('href',link).removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else{
      $('#a_next').attr('href','#').addClass('disabled');
    }             
});​
```

Comment: cant get it work :/
i always get a error

var link = "http://www.aerosoft.de" id="a_next";

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that this question isn't tagged with "jQuery", I'd suggested trapping the click event on the link and testing the radio buttons at that point.

Comment: @nnnnnn: That's what I thought. But by this approach he could also enable/disable the link visually to indicate that it is now "clickable".

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery,

**EDITED:**  (after comments; previous answer has an error)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#a_next').click(function(e){                 
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
               alert('Check all radios first');
               e.preventDefault();  // to stop anchor jumping to url
               return false;      // to break .each
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TWncG/)    ​

Comment: Needs to return false from the click handler, not just from the `.each()` callback.

Comment: Thats because , `return false` has different meaning in `.each()`. Let me correct